# Creating a linked list using a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, linked-list

I need to create a linked list of a class member (Binary), and I'm running into an infinite loop problem. The Binary class only contains the degree (int) and a next node pointer. 
Within the Binary Class, the implementation for the Binary linked list is being performed inside the set_bit method. The set_bit method takes in two ints, and they are either a 1/0 int (bit) and a degree int. The bit is not needed at this point though.

The set_bit method is below:

```
void Binary::set_bit(int b, int d){
    BinaryNode* current = firstTerm;
    BinaryNode* toSet;

    if (current == NULL) {

        firstTerm = new BinaryNode(d, NULL);
        current = firstTerm;

        cout << "\nd: " << d << " <--> current degree: " << current->degree << endl;
        system("pause");

    } else {
        while (current != NULL){
            firstTerm = new BinaryNode(d, current);
            cout << "\nd: " << d << " <--> current degree: " << current->degree << endl;
            cout << "first term: " << firstTerm->degree << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
}
```

on the main.cpp file, I am trying to set the following bits:

```
b1.set_bit(1, 2);
b1.set_bit(1, 5);
b1.set_bit(1, 0);
b1.set_bit(0, 2);
```

The method is setting the first bit (2), and gets to the next (5), then begins an infinite loop trying to set the bit. 
Where am I going wrong on this? 
I've asked my lab instructor for help and he provided me the following code: 
Why did the code that the lab instructor not work either?

```
void Binary ::set_bit( int b , int d ){
  BinaryNode * current = firstTerm;
  if (current == NULL ){
    firstTerm = new BinaryNode(d,NULL); // Corrected Line
  }
  while (current != NULL ){
    firstTerm = new BinaryNode(d,firstTerm); // Corrected Line 
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are not changing current in your while loop so the condition ( current != NULL ) will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you would end up with infinite loop, because when u try inserting the second node, `current != NULL` is always true, which means the `else` section is called. Unfortunately, the  there is a `while loop` inside whose condition is always true.

Comment: So, even if I create the new node->next == NULL, that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The only reason I was going with that setup was due to the code example that my lab instructor provided me. I am just trying to get it implemented and functional.